# PHP programatic POST not working

Tags: php, post, curl

I'm currently trying to send data from one server to another. It isn't anything complex, just a very long string (which means ~ 3-4 mb). I already tried multiple ways like fopen() and/or cURL but from a certain klipping point in the size of the string that should be send the $_POST['content'] appears to be empty all the time. Here's the code that I'm using:

```
    $post_data['content'] = $sql;

//traverse array and prepare data for posting (key1=value1)
foreach ( $post_data as $key => $value) {
    $post_items[] = $key . '=' . $value;
}

//create the final string to be posted using implode()
$post_string = implode ('&', $post_items);

//create cURL connection
$curl_connection =
  curl_init('http://myIP/myDir/myscript.php');

//set options
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,
  "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

//set data to be posted
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);

//perform our request
$result = curl_exec($curl_connection);

//show information regarding the request
//print_r(curl_getinfo($curl_connection));
echo curl_errno($curl_connection) . '-' .
                curl_error($curl_connection);

//close the connection
curl_close($curl_connection);`
```

The recieving script should write the content into my database, therefore it temporary writes the posted string into an file (cause I need to use Load Data Local In File for performance reasons):`$myFile = "/my/path/to/file.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($fh,$_POST['content']);
fclose($fh);`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried setting `CURLOPT_POST` to `TRUE`? If you had anything in `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` it's suppose to set it to `TRUE`, but that might not be working.

Comment: Also have you tried sending a smaller request? You might have a size limit on either end.

Comment: Also make sure that the keys and values of the `post_items` array are [urlencoded](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

Comment: like I mentioned, everything works fine. I'm working on a vServer, in my php.ini I set the following `post_max_size = 80M
allow_url_fopen = on
upload_max_filesize = 40M
memory_limit = 51200M
max_execution_time = 900000000`

Comment: What do you mean by "everything works fine"? I thought everything was *not* working fine, ergo, this question.

Comment: When the string is smaller in size and length everything is working fine, only when there are more chars inside the string which is passed the script stops working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shall use `http_build_query` function to create a query string try this:

```
$post_string = http_build_query($post_data);
```